# Separate access log to folder in Apache

Tags: apache-2.2, logging

Is there any way to make Apache create an access log for a single folder?

Files in this folder will be accessed very often, and I would prefer to avoid using any sort of script to generate the log.

An example would be something like:

```
/folder
/folder/often_access.txt 
/folder/often_access.exe
```

Ideally I'd like Apache to keep an access log of these files in rotation ie:

```
/folder/log/often_access.May2012.log
```

If that's possible, I could then create a script to read the log on demand.

I cannot use a subdomain as these files must go through HTTPS and we haven't got a wildcart certificate.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE:**
I expect some of these files will be accesses more often than 10-20 times a second. It's an update notifier. One of this files is a huge binary file and the other just a text containing latest version.

Answer (score 1):

You *could* use environment variables with [mod_setenvif](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_setenvif.html).

But why shouldn't you?  **Its a huge security risk**!  For example, such a function built into Apache would open up a DoS opportunity by overloading the number of file handles.  For this example, assume you can only have 16 files open on your server at once.  I can now wipe out those file descriptors by iterating through `/1`, `/2`, `/16`--there are now 16 logs that Apache must maintain.

The safest way (but by no means the most resource friendly) would be to pipe each request to a script:

```
CustomLog "|/some/script/for/parsing/logs" combined
```

This won't eliminate the above options--but it will allow you to have a lot more flexibility in where the logs go, as well as alleviating Apache's responsibility in maintaining your server's stability.

Finally, what you *should* be doing is exactly what you don't want to do--processing these after the fact.  What you're looking for is some sort of aggregate parsing--i.e., which lines dealt with some unique set of directories.  How often is this realistically going to be used?  If its not often, what's wrong with just `grep`ing the logs and displaying its output?  These are the kinds of questions you should ask first.

Comment: Unfortunately, my answer remains the same--its not a good idea to dynamically create log files.

Comment: Can "CustomLog" be used within .htaccess somehow?

Comment: No, and for the same reason--the logs need to be started BEFORE everything else.  On shared hosting as well, this could lead to the same security exploits I mentioned above.